# how add csv file in rasa chatbot as intent and responses?

Tags: csv, chatbot, rasa, rasa-nlu, nlu

For rasa chatbot I have comma separated values (CSV) file , how can I add my .csv data to the rasa chatbot for input as intent and responses.

trying to add training data as csv , But it not working , How can I convert this csv to nlu.yml